# Disable .slideUp function when mouse hover sub menu

Tags: javascript, menu, hover, submenu, slideup

I have a small problem. I want that when I hover mouse on the sub menu, when it is open, the sub menu is not collapsing. Thanks.

```
$('.navigation').find('ul').parent().addClass('lv2-menu');

    $('.lv2-menu').hover(

        function(){

            el = $(this);

            el.find('ul').stop(false,true).slideDown(1000);

        },
        function(){

            el = $(this);

            el.find('ul').stop(false,true).slideUp(1000);

        }
    )


    $('.navigation').find('.lv2-menu').each(function(){

        el = $(this);

        if(el.find('.current-menu-item').size()){

            el.addClass('show-sub');
            el.find('ul').css({'display':'block'});
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event listeners. For the `onmouseover` function, have the element slide down. For the `onmouseout` function, have the element slide back up.

[mouseOver](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

[mouseOut](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)